# Assetic get_image with variable as argument

Tags: php, image, symfony, twig, assetic

can anybody tell me why this:

```
{% for key, logo in it %}
{% set imageUrl = "bundles/acme/img/it/"~logo %}
<li><img src="{{ get_image(imageUrl) }}" alt="{{ key }}"0/></li>
{% endfor %}
```

causes this:

```
An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Attribute "value" does not exist for Node "Twig_Node_Expression_Name".")
```

Thx for any advice

Comment: please provide the twig extension/macro providing `get_image()` - you would normally use the `asset()` function (see my answer). And why is there a trailing `0` in your `<img>` tag?

Comment: Is that related to assetic ?

Comment: @nifr my bad about 0 sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `asset()` method instead ...

```
{% for key, logo in it %}
   {% set imageUrl = "bundles/acme/img/it/"~logo %}
   <li><img src="{{ asset(imageUrl) }}" alt="{{ key }}"/></li>
{% endfor %}
```